# WatchOS2 connectivity framework doesn't work

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchos-2, wcsession

I want to pass data from Iphone to Apple Watch. I tried everything but when I am using the `didReceiveUserInfo` function, nothing happens I check if WCSession is compatible and it is.

Code on my Iphone:

```
if(ipField.text != ""){
                do {
                    try watchSession?.transferUserInfo(["name" : "test"])
                    print("context update")

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    NSLog("Updating the context failed: " + error.localizedDescription)
                    print("failed")
                   }
```

Code on my Apple Watch:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]){

    let Value = userInfo["name"] as? String

    self.currentIpLabel.setText(Value)
    print("done1")

}
```

WCSESSION check Iphone:

```
  if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
            let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
            session.delegate = self
            session.activateSession()

            print("SUPPORT OK")
        }
```

WCSESSION check AppleWatch

```
  if(WCSession.isSupported()){
            watchSession = WCSession.defaultSession()
            // Add self as a delegate of the session so we can handle messages
            watchSession!.delegate = self
            watchSession!.activateSession()

        }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors return on the sending side in the didTransferUserInfo callback? If not, please post the code where you activate the session on both sides as well as the code to send the user info and the code to receive it

Comment: @ccjensen Hi, I added the code in my question. I do not get any errors.

Comment: Do you have a solution? @ccjensen

Comment: Could you add the code where you activate the WCSession on the phone and watch side? Also, the transferUserInfo API call doesn't throw an error, but instead you should on the sending side implement didTransferUserInfo delegate callback to see if the sending side thinks the transfer was successful

Comment: @ccjensen Hi, Added the code for `WCSESSION`

Comment: It also prints support Ok @ccjensen

Comment: Thanks. Did you try adding the didTransferUserInfo delegate callback on the sending side? Does it get called with or without an error?

Comment: @ccjensen I do not see an error when calling `   
                func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {
                    
                        print("test")
                }

Comment: Just to confirm; on the sending side after calling transferUserInfo you do get the delegate callback didTransferUserInfo with no error?

Comment: Yes with no error @ccjensen

Comment: Hmmm... Nothing obviously wrong sticks out. I'd suggest maybe putting the entire test project up on github for us to take a look, or maybe file a bug report with Apple

Comment: Thanks! What is your Github username, I will create a private repo and invite you. @ccjensen

Comment: I can't create a private repo because it is not free, the repo is: https://github.com/Techchunky/controlApp @ccjensen

Hope you can help :D

Comment: Is the link working? @ccjensen

Comment: yes, the link works. I'll take a look at the code and reply back later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created an issue on github with a suggested patch attached. I tested this version of the app on my own devices and the watch received the userInfo just fine. The main change I made was to move the declaration of the WCSessionDelegate methods from being "nested functions" to top level functions in the file. Nested functions are only available from within the scope of the function they are defined in, which would mean that the delegate object wouldn't have implementations for those methods.

Comment: I als can send from apple watch to iphone, Working Amazing! but when I close my app I can't do that anymore, is there a way which can allow it? @ccjensen

Comment: this sounds like a separate question :) but if you are asking how a watch app can communicate with an iOS app that is not currently running, then the sendMessage API can wake it up in the background (make sure to check the isReachable property before using sendMessage)

Comment: Thanks I added this code        let applicationData = ["counterValue":"testmessage"]
            //
            watchSession!.sendMessage(applicationData, replyHandler: {(_: [String : AnyObject]) -> Void in
                // handle reply from iPhone app here
                }, errorHandler: {(error ) -> Void in
                    // catch any errors here
            })

And it works even when the app is closed but what I find strange is: I only added this code to the watch I didn't add anything to the app

Comment: this would be better handled by a separate question. For sendMessage and waking the iOS app in the background make sure that WCSession is being activated even when the iOS app runs in the background, and make sure all those WCSessionDelegate methods are defined at the delegate class' top level rather than as nested functions